# React-addons-css-transition-group styling

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations

I'm trying to create tabs in React JS and I want to add some animation to it using React-addons-css-transition-group.

My code is as follows :

```
render() {

    let view = this.state.tiresView ? this.renderTiresView() : this.renderOptionsView();

    return (
        <div >
            <div className="tiresFeaturesTitle">
                <Link to="" onClick={this.changeView.bind(this, "options")} >Options</Link>
                <Link to="" onClick={this.changeView.bind(this, "tires")} >Tires</Link>
            </div>
            <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionEnterTimeout={500} transitionLeaveTimeout={500} transitionAppear={true} transitionAppearTimeout={500}>
                <div key={this.state.tiresView}>
                    {view}
                </div>
            </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The styles for `example` are :

```
.example-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}

.example-enter.example-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.example-leave {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}

.example-leave.example-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}

.example-appear {
  opacity: 0.01;
}

.example-appear.example-appear-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}
```

It works fine, but when I change tab I see the old one too for about half a second. I do not want that.

I want that when I click to change tab the old one disappears immediately.

[image]

You can see on the photo what I mean. I clicked to change the tab view to tires, but for a second I see the old tab content `this is options view` below. I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved by adding `display:none` to `.example-leave` class.

The working css is as follows :

```
.example-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}

.example-enter.example-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.example-leave {
  display: none;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}

.example-leave.example-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}

.example-appear {
  opacity: 0.01;
}

.example-appear.example-appear-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}
```

Comment: You're right. The transition for leaving tab is lost, but that transition is not needed. I have transition on entering a new tab.

Comment: Thanks for the help in any case. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `position: absolute` to `.example-leave` ? Might not solve the problem but I think what is happening is that you need to fix the style for this class.

Comment: The same problem. Now I see the content of the old tab at the top and not below the new one.

Comment: What do you mean by on top ? What if you wrap your ReactCSSTransitionGroup into a `<div style={{position:'relative'}} />`

Comment: No, the same problem. See the photo in my question. On the photo `This is Options view` shows at the bottom. Now with your style it shows at the top.

Comment: I would stubbornly try to add a `position: absolute` to `.example-enter` as well. But maybe it is too dumb

Comment: I solved it by adding `display: none;` to `.example-leave`